# D&D 3.5 Podcasts

Tags: dnd-3.5e, podcast

Aside from "[3.5 Private Sanctuary](http://knowdirectionpodcast.com/category/podcasts/35-private-sanctuary/)", are there any other podcasts that regularly cover the 3.5 or d20 system?

Answer (score 2):

I used to subscribe to [Radio Free Hommelet](http://hommlet.com/), that podcast is part of [d20 radio](http://start.d20radio.com/) network and includes a pathfinder specific podcast called [Chronicles](http://www.justiceradio.net/podcast/) as well as several other d20 based podcasts.

Comment: Only the d20 Radio link still works (and just barely).

Comment: Well, my answer is 7 years old. 

http://geekandsundry.com/shows/critical-role/ Critical Role is a a bunch of voice actors playing a pathfinder-ish campaign on you tube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-cuqqHGpRDE Harmon Quest is the same but with TV people. 

http://partyrollpodcast.com/ is a 5e game podcast.

These are all games being played as a podcast/videocast. I don't listen to any podcasts now (7 years later) that just discuss game rules.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  For some reason this popped to the top of the question list.  I just wanted to point out to let people know in case it popped up again.